# Same working query doesn't work when comparing dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this:

```
where
    (trunc(my_date) >= (trunc(to_date('06/03/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) + INTERVAL '13:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND))
  AND
    (trunc(my_date) < (trunc(to_date('06/03/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) + INTERVAL '15:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND))
```

The weird thing is that the bottom part works as expected and the top one doesn't.

I'm trying to get this value: `2020-06-03 13:42:31.862930`

The funny thing is that if I change the one above the `AND` to `06/02/2020`, it would include it...
What's going on here?

Comment: What is `my_date` data type ?

Comment: @pifor give me a sec, let me check

Comment: @pifor TIMESTAMP(6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove trunc function:

```
SQL> select * from t;

MY_DATE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-06-03 13:42:31.862930


SQL> select trunc(my_date) from t;

TRUNC(MY_DATE)
-------------------
2020-06-03 00:00:00


SQL> --
SQL> select * from t
  2  where
  3      ((my_date) >= (trunc(to_date('06/03/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) + INTERVAL '13:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND))
  4    AND
  5      ((my_date) < (trunc(to_date('06/03/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) + INTERVAL '15:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND))
  6  ;

MY_DATE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-06-03 13:42:31.862930
```

Comment: Is that safe to not truncate the date?

Comment: It all depends of what you want to do. But for this query you need to not truncate the date. And if you have TIMESTAMP(6) it's also for hours, minutes, seconds and more -  not just for year, day and month.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your date is a calculated date?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities

A) comparison **with the time component** - then use this expression

```
my_date  < (to_date('06/03/2020','MM/DD/YYYY') + INTERVAL '15:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND)
```

B) comparison **without the time component** (i.e. truncated) - then use this expression

```
trunc(my_date) <  trunc(to_date('06/03/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')
```

*Your combination fails to have an interpretation for me*